# Lim inf of subsequence less than lim inf

Tags: convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a compact set and $(x_n,y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset X\;$ be a sequence. Assume that $x_n$ converges to $x^*$. By Bolzano-Weierstrass it is known that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k},x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ which converges to $(x^*,y^*:=\liminf_{k\rightarrow \infty}\;y_{n_k})\in X$ as it is clearly a limit point of $(x_n,y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\;$.

I would like to show that if $x_n\rightarrow x^*$ then$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}y_n \geq y^* .$$

By definition we have $$\liminf_{k\rightarrow \infty}y_{n_k}= y^*,$$ but in general we have $$y^*=\liminf_{k\rightarrow \infty}y_{n_k}\geq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n.$$What am I missing, or is it even possible to show what I want to show? To be clear I only need $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\; y_n$ to be equal or greater than some arbritary $y^*$ where $(x^*,y^*)\in X$. Thank you.

Comment: Why would $(x_{n_k}, x_{n_k}) \to (x^*, y^*)$?

Comment: $x_{n_k}$ converges to $x^*$ because $x_n$ converges to $x^*$ (given assumption). $y^*$ is just the limit of the $y_{n_k}$ subsequence which converges by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question, since if the subsequence $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is chosen to be convergent, then
$$
y^\ast=\liminf_{k\to\infty}y_{n_k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}y_{n_k},
$$
so no need to consider limes inferior, but you cannot a priori define $y^\ast=\liminf_{k\to\infty}y_{n_k}$, since you have not specified the subsequence $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Maybe you meant to write $y^\ast=\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n$, but then the rest of the question doesn't really make sense.

I will try to answer what I think you are asking. Feel free to comment if I have misunderstood! Let's ignore $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $x^\ast$ and just take some arbitrary subsequence $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Here, $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ may be any sequence of real numbers. Then, for each $N\in\mathbb{N}$, we clearly have
$$
\{ y_{n_k}\mid k\in\mathbb{N},k\geq N\}\subseteq\{ y_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq N\},
$$
and thus
$$
\inf\{ y_{n_k}\mid k\in\mathbb{N},k\geq N\}\geq\inf\{ y_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq N\}.
$$
Letting $N\to\infty$, we get
$$
\liminf_{k\to\infty}y_{n_k}\geq\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for asking in a dumb way. What I want to achieve is the last inequality the other way around. I want to somehow bound $y_n$ from below, possibly by using a subsequence $y_{n_k}$ which is known to be bound from below as it converges. $y_{n_k}$ should exist by Bolzano-Weierstrass as all points are within a compact set.

Comment: Well, if you consider the function $p_2:X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $p_2(x,y)=y$, this is clearly continuous, and since $X$ is compact, $p_2$ attains its minimum, meaning there exists some $(x_m,y_m)\in X$ such that $y=p_2(x,y)\geq p_2(x_m,y_m)=y_m$ for all $(x,y)\in X$. Since $(x^\ast,\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n)\in X$, we get $\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n\geq y_m$. Is that good enough?

Comment: It seems correct but I wonder why no converging subsequence is needed. I am actually trying to understand a proof from a paper given in another context and there a converging subsequence was used. Is there some meaningful way such subsequence could be added, or did I just oversimplify the question?

Comment: Well in general, $\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n$ is the smallest limit point of $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, and since it seems you have chosen an arbitrary subsequence, it will not in general have a smaller limit than $\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n$. But again, I don't think you formulated very clearly how this subsequence is being chosen. Maybe you could link this paper?